# String Django Format Template

Tags: python, django, string

I have a problem, thats probably very simple,

I have a list of strings,  that I pass as variable to a template called s_name

If I print the list elements on the view side I see them ok,  but on the html they got rendered this way

> ['PB14'],  ['HHZ']

In order to rescue each element, I'm doing slicing on the list,

```
  {% with y=forloop.counter0|stringformat:"s" %}
  {% with z=forloop.counter0|add:1|stringformat:"s" %}
  {%  with mySlice=""|add:y|add:":"|add:z %}
  {{ s_name|slice:mySlice }}
  {% endwith %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% endwith %}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `s_name` look like in the view?

Comment: If i print it, just  PB14 , HHZ  with no ' neither [

Comment: It appears Django's `slice` only works on a list (see docs). The results may vary when you're not passing a list.

Comment: If you just want to print the strings it's as simple as `{% for s in yourlist %}{{ s }}{% endfor %}`. Else please explain what result you expect...

Comment: I'm inside a loop yet, that is why I use this "slicing" 

I just want to see the strings without ' neither [

Comment: The problem was that the output of slice was another list,  (thanks @SimeonVisser)

So the solution was to convert to a string again using `{{ value|join:"" }} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the output of slice was another list,  (thanks @SimeonVisser)

So the solution was to convert to a string again using `{{ value|join:"" }}`